# Change UITabBarView tabs order programmatically

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have an app I want to run with the option of 2 languages - First one you read from right to let, the other from left to right.

I want to be able to change tabs order in `UITabBarController` according to the selected language, programmatically.

How can this be done?

Comment: Like you have given default order to Tabs like this: self.viewControllers = [tabOne, tabTwo]. You can change update the view on language change and set order to self.viewControllers = [tabTwo, tabOne]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to set the items in reverse manually by calling tabView's `setItems()` method and array's `reversed()` method in the delegate method `viewWillAppear(_:)`, but first you'd want to somehow check if the language is left to right or right to left.

```
self.tabBar.setItems(self.tabBar.items?.reversed(), animated: false)
```